# xxx.png and xxx@2x.png trouble in retina graphics compatibility

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, retina-display

Now, the project require supporting *iPad1*, *iPad2*, the new iPad, iPad with Retina display. So I need to add `xxx.png` and `xxx@2x.png` these kinds of pictures into the project bundle, and everything is normal when I run the app in *iPad1* or *iPad2*. But the question is, all `xxx@2x.png` will not be used in the new iPad and iPad with Retina display when I choose iOS 5.0 as my project deployment target.

However, all `xxx@2x.png` will work very well if I choose iOS 5.1 or later version, and it doesn't matter with the project based SDK version, iOS 5.0, 5.1, 6.1, all work well.

Have you ever met this problem?

By the way, there is no problem in iPad Simulator, no matter which version of simulator.

Comment: How do you know for a fact which png version is being utilized?

Comment: did you do clean? cmd+shift+k

Comment: for better output reset simulator

Comment: @Stavash It's easy. I draw a red circle in xxx@2x.png

Comment: @torip3ng Clean? It doesn't work.

Comment: It just occurs in iPad device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got it.

As these three pictures showing below:

[image: Based SDKs]

[image: Deployment Target]

[image: Based SDK in Run Scheme]

The key to the question is, that Xcode must compile project by based SDK 5.1 or later. But the based SDK is not the one in project settings. Like me, I put three versions of iOS SDK into the directory, so there are 3 devices in Run Scheme(as picture3 shows) and its order is the same as the based SDK. I need choose based SDK iOS 5.1 or later in Run Scheme, then it will work well.